# InlinePart. What is it and what happened to it?

Tags: undocumented, deprecated

So a while back I was searching for an unused high-application order symbol I could use for an OOP framework and I ran across `InlinePart (esc @> esc)` in my UnicodeCharacters.tr file with an application precedence of 763 (e.g. when parsing an expression using this its formatting rules are called before those of, say, `[]`).

When I actually use the symbol though I get this:

```
In[63]:= a \[InlinePart] b[10]

Out[63]= RowBox[{a, InlinePart, b}][10]
```

For those curious the symbol looks like this: [image: row part]

And the only reference I could find to it (outside of styling stuff or other formatting things) was [this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2234/2014/5/7).

So what was it? Why'd it go?

Comment: I also found nothing. Not via PrintDefinitions nor anwhere else in the documentation nor in the Internet. Only a file where the shortcut was defined you've already given. I like to think, that this is simple a symbol Wolfram reserved for something a user could use for implementing new things like you want to. But i doubt it. I experimented a little bit with it but didn't found any particular use-case or other pattern beside the one already observed. This is strange. 
So: good question.

Comment: I think it was removed based on the chat I found / linked to. R. M. seemed to know what it was so hopefully he will stop by and enlighten us poor souls.

Comment: Interesting discovery.  I'll have to read that file more carefully.  Note also the behavior of `InlinePart[a, b]`

Comment: And if you do ``System`Private`HasAnyCodesQ@InlinePart`` it appears to have been scrubbed from the kernel too.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`InlinePart` or `@>` was an operator that was introduced in one of the pre-release/betas for version 10 and subsequently removed before public release. It was briefly available publicly in the Raspberry Pi version of Wolfram Language that co-existed with the pre-releases at the time.

The operator allowed you to access elements of a list with an infix operator. Both of these would have been equivalent:

```
list = {1, 2, 3};

list @> 2 (* InlinePart *)
list[[2]] (* Part *)
```

I think it was also more flexible than that and allowed you to access keys of `Associations` with `assoc @> "key"` syntax. The thinking probably might have been that this syntactic sugar would make it easy to chain or "drill" into a dataset with `dataset @> key1 @> key2 @> key3`

If I had to guess why it was discontinued, I would think that it was because it didn't bring much to the table while adding a lot of overhead (both for the end user and for the developers) and fundamentally altering a core symbol `Part`.

- You couldn't use `;;` or `Span` for flexible indexing.
- There is the potential for visual confusion with `@` and friends.
- I don't remember, but there might have been some precedence issues as well. For example, `f @ g @> 2` might have been parsed as `(f @ g) @> 2` instead of `f @ (g @> 2)` which is different from using `[[]]` (I could be misremembering this).

I think in lieu of this operator, `Associations` was modified to support the function call syntax so that you could do `assoc @ "key"` which achieved the same while being more idiomatic/Mathematica like.

My memory is hazy and some parts about the motivations are speculative, but I think this is a fair summary of what this operator did during its short life. [Taliesin Beynon](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/7140/taliesin-beynon) will know more about this if you're really interested in an authoritative answer :)

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Its high parsing precedence and interesting appearance made me want it for overloading property calls, but then I just got really curious.

Comment: In the notebook front end, if you type `\[In` you get a drop-down list of autocompletion suggestions. `\[InlinePart]` is in that list (as is `\[InvisibleApplication]`, one of my favorites. It appears that the documentation and evaluation rules of of `\[InlinePart]` have been removed, but not all traces of its existence. You will get the appropriate Unicode character and the `RowBox` result as in the originally posted question, at least in MMA 11.0.3 on Linux.