# What does the return value of Internal`ArgumentCountRegistry mean?

Tags: undocumented, built-in-symbols, internals

`` Internal`ArgumentCountRegistry `` sometimes will give a value about some function.Such as

```
Internal`ArgumentCountRegistry /@ {DisjointQ, Autocomplete, 
  AssociationMap, CountDistinct, CountDistinct, CountDistinctBy, 
  Decapitalize, DeleteDuplicatesBy, DeleteMissing, DeleteSearchIndex, 
  IntersectingQ, LanguageIdentify, NetModel, NetReplacePart}
```

> {{1,2},{1,3},{1,2},{1,2},{1,2},{1,2},{1,1},{1,2},{1,3},{1,1},{1,2},{1,1},{1,2},{2,2}}

But what's meaning of this result?

Comment: I'm gonna guess it's how many are required and what the max number is or something along those lines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I put this in a comment but now I'm relatively more sure. I think the first number is how the minimum number of arguments allowed and the right is the maximum. I'm guessing this is in some way input by the devs because it hasn't been updated for 11. Here's how I know. I ran this:

```
mapped =
  DeleteCases[
   AssociationMap[
    If[Length@ToExpression[#, StandardForm, OwnValues] == 0 && 
       MatchQ[ToExpression@#, _Symbol],
      Internal`ArgumentCountRegistry@ToExpression@#,
      Nothing
      ] &,
    Names[]
    ],
   Nothing
   ];

Select[
 mapped,
 MatchQ[Except[_Internal`ArgumentCountRegistry]]
 ]
```

And it spat out a big association of stuff:

```
<|"GeneralUtilities`AppendAt" -> {3, 3}, 
 "GeneralUtilities`AppendToAt" -> {3, 3}, 
 "GeneralUtilities`AssociatePairs" -> {1, 1}, 
 "AssociationMap" -> {1, 2}, 
 "GeneralUtilities`AssociationPairs" -> {1, 1}, 
 "Autocomplete" -> {1, 3}, 
 "GeneralUtilities`BlockProtected" -> {2, 2}, 
 "GeneralUtilities`CacheTo" -> {3, 3}, "CountDistinct" -> {1, 2}, 
 "CountDistinctBy" -> {1, 2}, "Decapitalize" -> {1, 1}, 
 "GeneralUtilities`DeepCases" -> {1, 2}, 
 "GeneralUtilities`DeepUniqueCases" -> {1, 2}, 
 "DeleteDuplicatesBy" -> {1, 2}, "DeleteMissing" -> {1, 3}, 
 "DeleteSearchIndex" -> {1, 1}, "DisjointQ" -> {1, 2}, 
 "GeneralUtilities`FirstMatchIndex" -> {1, 3}, 
 "GeneralUtilities`FlatMap" -> {1, 2}, 
 "GeneralUtilities`FoldEmit" -> {3, 3}, 
 "GeneralUtilities`FoldEmitRecurse" -> {3, 3}, 
 "GeneralUtilities`FoldRecurse" -> {3, 3}, 
 "GeneralUtilities`IndexBy" -> {1, 2}, 
 "GeneralUtilities`IndexOf" -> {1, 3}, 
 "GeneralUtilities`IndicesOf" -> {1, 2}, "IntersectingQ" -> {1, 2}, 
 "GeneralUtilities`JoinMap" -> {1, 2}, 
 "GeneralUtilities`MapIf" -> {2, 3}, 
 "GeneralUtilities`MapSequence" -> {1, \[Infinity]}, 
 "GeneralUtilities`MatchIndices" -> {1, 2}, 
 "GeneralUtilities`PairQ" -> {1, 1}, 
 "GeneralUtilities`PosetSort" -> {2, 2}, "PowerRange" -> {1, 3}, 
 "PrintableASCIIQ" -> {1, 1}, 
 "GeneralUtilities`PropertyAssociation" -> {1, 1}, 
 "GeneralUtilities`ReapBag" -> {1, 1}, 
 "GeneralUtilities`ScanIndexed" -> {1, 3}, 
 "GeneralUtilities`ScanThread" -> {1, 2}, "SearchIndices" -> {0, 0}, 
 "GeneralUtilities`SelectFirstIndex" -> {1, 3}, 
 "GeneralUtilities`SelectIndices" -> {1, 2}, "Snippet" -> {1, 2}, 
 "GeneralUtilities`SowBag" -> {1, 1}, 
 "StringExtract" -> {2, \[Infinity]}, "StringPadLeft" -> {1, 3}, 
 "StringPadRight" -> {1, 3}, 
 "GeneralUtilities`StringPatternQ" -> {1, 1}, 
 "StringRepeat" -> {2, 3}, "StringRiffle" -> {2, \[Infinity]}, 
 "SubsetQ" -> {1, 2}, "TextSearch" -> {2, 2}, 
 "TextSearchReport" -> {2, 2}, "TextString" -> {1, 1}, 
 "GeneralUtilities`ToAssociations" -> {1, 1}, 
 "GeneralUtilities`ToCamelCase" -> {1, 1}, 
 "GeneralUtilities`ToTitleCase" -> {1, 1}, 
 "GeneralUtilities`TransposeTo" -> {1, 2}, 
 "GeneralUtilities`TrimLeft" -> {1, 1}, 
 "GeneralUtilities`TrimRight" -> {1, 1}, 
 "GeneralUtilities`UniqueCases" -> {1, 2}, 
 "UpdateSearchIndex" -> {1, 1}|>
```

And I checked all the non `` GeneralUtilities` `` stuff in the docs and checked some of the GU stuff from the `DownValues` and it *mostly* works out. All is correct except for `TextSearch`, but I can't find the v10 docs for `TextSearch` to see if there's been a change in the allowed arguments. On the other hand, everything I found there was added in 10.x which suggests that no updates were done for the new in 11. stuff.

It's curious, but it seems to make sense. Of course I could also be flat-out wrong. Just speculating here.

Comment: Little strange,you mean `DisjointQ` can accept on argument?

Comment: Yep. Check out `DisjointQ[{1, 2, 3}]@{1, 2, 3}`. It can clearly behave as an operator.

Comment: Well,I don't know this usage of `DisjointQ` before this..

Comment: @yode It's says that they're not disjoint, which I think counts as working. The `SyntaxInformation` suggests it can't, but clearly it can.

Comment: And funny,[this list](https://ooo.0o0.ooo/2017/03/16/58ca2cf32c469.jpg) don't include that usage of `Disjoint`,and the document either.

Comment: @yode I'm gonna guess they had it in for some beta version or something, then deprecated it by making it undocumented. [A similar thing happened to `InlinePart`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134506/inlinepart-what-is-it-and-what-happened-to-it)