# Get list of special characters

Tags: built-in-symbols, input-forms, introspection

I recently found that `\[Gradient]` and `\[InlinePart]` both expand (contract) to special symbols in MMA.

So far as I can tell (see [InlinePart. What is it and what happened to it?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134506/inlinepart-what-is-it-and-what-happened-to-it)) they have no built in meaning.  Further, I can't find any Wolfram documentation of them, even in https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ListingOfNamedCharacters.html.

Is there some introspection that can list all special symbols that expand like `\[stuff]`?  The same goes for symbols entered as `\[AliasDelimiter]stuff\[AliasDelimiter]`.

---

Here's what the symbols look like

[image: symbols]

---

OK the second part of the question concerns `InputAlias`s, which don't seem to be collected in any one place, but are sprinkled throughout the filesystem, for instance, in Mathematica/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/TextResources/CommonFrontEndInit.tr

This question, then, amounts to basically lamenting that no method so far lists *all* of the existing glyphs.  So far there's

- the Wolfram ListingOfNamedCharacters, missing many
- UnicodeCharacters.tr, missing a bit fewer glyphs
- Brute forcing with `"PrintableASCII"` export of every char code, missing only a couple

Answer (score 3):

I copy pasted the input strings from the Listing of (not all) Named Characters, excluding the unicode characters and dashes.  There are 1009 elements in that `list`.

I went grepping for the text `\[Gradient]`.

- Mathematica/SystemFiles/Libraries/Linux-x86-64/libWolframEngine.so has it, compiled in for some reason
- Mathematica/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/TextResources/UnicodeCharacters.tr has it, bingo!

I don't know how to read the .tr files, but sure enough the symbols, categorized and with unicode codes, are there.  There are 972 of them after taking

```
Cases[list,x_/;StringStartsQ[x,"\\["]\[And]StringEndsQ[x,"]"]\[And]StringLength@x>3]
```

and let's put them in `unlisted`.  Now

```
DeleteCases[unlisted,Alternatives@@list]
```

yields

```
{"\\[Rupee]", "\\[VectorGreater]", "\\[VectorGreaterEqual]", 
"\\[VectorLess]", "\\[VectorLessEqual]", "\\[Limit]", "\\[MaxLimit]", 
"\\[MinLimit]", "\\[CubeRoot]", "\\[Minus]", "\\[DivisionSlash]", 
"\\[Laplacian]", "\\[Divergence]", "\\[Curl]", "\\[ProbabilityPr]", 
"\\[ExpectationE]", "\\[Shah]", "\\[ContinuedFractionK]", 
"\\[Gradient]", "\\[InlinePart]", "\\[Villa]", "\\[Akuz]", 
"\\[Andy]", "\\[Spooky]", "\\[UnknownGlyph]", 
"\\[COMPATIBILITYNoBreak]", "\\[KeyBar]", "\\[ShiftKey]", 
"\\[Mod1Key]", "\\[Mod2Key]", "\\[PageBreakAbove]", 
"\\[PageBreakBelow]", "\\[NumberComma]", "\\[FreeformPrompt]", 
"\\[WolframAlphaPrompt]"}
```

which is pretty cool.  No respect for India in the docs!  Also I'm disappointed that `\[Spooky]` just shows up as the rectangle with x on my system.

Unfortunately, I've been beaten to the punch: [Which operators are missing from the official precedence table?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/135805/which-operators-are-missing-from-the-official-precedence-table) already notes UnicodeCharacters.tr.

Answer (score 2):

The list of keyboard shortcuts for the Wolfram language and System is [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/KeyboardShortcutListing.html).

The list of named characters for the Wolfram language and System is [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ListingOfNamedCharacters.html).

For system names, try: `` Names["System`*"] `` (* edit suggested by Adam Thanks *)

---------- edit---- More digging for programmatic retrieval of special characters.

[@LouisB](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/104299/how-could-get-all-escape-characters-in-mathematica) has a solution here.

[@george2017](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7610/list-of-mathematica-glyphs) posted a solution here 9 years ago.

With some effort:

[image]

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: See if you can format ``Names["System`*"]`` (hint, no need to escape ' if you use "... similar for `)!

Comment: I like the `FromCharacterCode` approach.  Unfortunately all three approaches miss some glyphs (Wolfram listing, file spelunking, and programmatic generation).  The glyphs produced only by the unicode search are `\[TwoWayRule],\[Moon],\[Sun],\[CheckmarkedBox]` and `\[StepperULDR]` where `ULDR` is a direction: neat!

Comment: And the efficacy of the other approaches: the Wolfram listing offers nothing new compared to both system appraoches, and my spelunking offers only `\[COMPATIBILITYNoBreak]` compared to the list+unicode searching.